# If P = NP, can all NP problems be solved within time $O(n^k)$ for fixed $k$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np

I came across this question while studying for an exam:

> T/F: Suppose we can show for some fixed $k$, an NP-complete problem P has a time $O(n^k)$ algorithm. Then every problem in NP has a $O(n^k)$ time algorithm.

I think the answer is false, since we can't reduce NP-complete to NP-hard in linear time, right? Or am I completely misunderstanding reductions/NP problems? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the answer the the question is "false".

By contradiction, assume every problem in $NP$ has a $O(n^k)$ algorithm, for some fixed $k$. That is, $NP \subseteq {\sf DTIME}(O(n^k))$

This would contradict the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), which implies the *strict* inclusion

$$
{\sf DTIME}(O(n^k)) \subset
{\sf DTIME}(O(n^{2k}))
$$

However, we also have

$$
{\sf DTIME}(O(n^{2k})) \subseteq NP \subseteq
{\sf DTIME}(O(n^{k}))
$$

which contradicts the previous strict inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

> If $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{NP}$, can all $\mathbf{NP}$ problems be solved within time $O(n^k)$ for fixed $k$?

No, because the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says that there are problems that can be solved in time $O(n^{k+1})$ that can't be solved in time $O(n^k)$.

> we can't reduce NP-complete to NP-hard in linear time

Any $\mathbf{NP}$-complete problem is $\mathbf{NP}$-hard by definition.

Comment: Note that the title is my attempt at creating a more snappy yet accurate one than the OP's. For that, I assumed that P = NP as a consequence of the problem statement was obvious.

Comment: @Raphael OK. I still think my answer is appropriate to the question body.